# Apache How do I make it so other IP Address's can go into a folder but only if they login

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, htpasswd

So I want to be able to access my "home" admin folder at school but I cant so how do I make it so I can with .htpasswd file and then allow access but I got it to work once but gave me a 500 error...

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html

Use htpasswd for the user auth and setup the necessary Require statements if you want to do IP/host filtering.

Sorry to not be exactly specific but it can get complex.  If the data is not super super secret just go with the htpasswd for user auth especially if you are on a home/dhcp connection don't want to lock yourself out.